# Surfaces of revolution with a more complex function

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion, trigonometric-integrals

for a paper that I need to write for my math class for the IB diploma programme I was interested in modeling the surface area of different kinds of bottles: I initially wanted to use this formula:

Formula:

> $$A=2\pi\int_a^bf(x)\sqrt{1+[f’(x)]^2}dx$$

However, I quickly realized that many of my functions that I generated via applying curve fitting on the bottles that I had been planning on applying this formula to (in order to find the surface area of the bottles) were more complex trigonometric functions.The paper I'm writing is very limited in space, and I'm obligated to explain the steps taken thoroughly. This makes me wonder, would it be appropriate to try and approximate these trigonometric functions as polynomials instead because I feel like the formula would be easier to apply to them? Apologies if this seems like a straightforward question, we were not taught anything about Taylor Series in class and it is not in the syllabus for the course I'm taking :p

Comment: Even for polynomial $f$ the integrals quickly become unmanageable---already for a generic cubic polynomial $f$ expressing the integral requires elliptic functions. For most functions the integrand is not going to have a closed-form antiderivative, so you'll probably want to use numerical methods to approximate the surface area, and for that purpose trigonometric functions are not typically worse than polynomial ones.

Comment: Why would I need elliptic equations? for example if we start off with the function y = x^3 the derivative is simply 3x^2. Squaring that we get 9x^4. Now plugging that into the formula we can take the integral of x^3 times sqrt of 9x^4 +1 and it can be solved via simple u subsitution.. this is what I'm aiming for.

Comment: Try $x+x^3$ or pretty much any term added to $x^3$

Comment: @Momxro Like I wrote, the comment applies to generic cubics. For example, try taking $f(x) = x^3 + x^2$ and integrating. (Incidentally, using a function $x^3 + a x$ does give an integral that can be evaluated in closed form.)

Comment: One thing you need to understand: It is not necessary to find some "closed form" expression for every integral that you deal with. Admittedly, they are nice to have when available, but in fact, all you need is an expression that allows you to calculate the value to any desired-but-finite accuracy, and the integral expression itself fits that bill. Even closed form expressions do no better than this, which is why we only know the value of $\pi$ to a few trillion digits, not perfectly.